# How can I save the model that I downloaded?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

Now i have error because method save not found
For example

```
const model = cocoSsd.load();
await model.save('indexeddb://my-model');
```

Answer (score 0):

cocoSsd does not have a save `method` resulting in the error:

> method save not found

Since the model is not used for training, there is not point in saving it as if a certain state of the model will be retrieved later. The same model can be loaded each time it is needed or simply kept in memory.